# nao consigo colocar os logotipos do lado do direito da tela, ao lado do titulo, eles ficam em baixo da div no lado direito

Tags: html, css

html

```
        <h2>WANTED</h2>
        <div class="">
        </div><!--menu principal-->
        </div><!--header-1-->
        </div><!--logo-->
        <div class="redes-sociais">
            <ul>
                
                <li><a href=""><img src="imagens/instagram.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="imagens/linkedin.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="imagens/twitter.png"></a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </main>
</header>
```

css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: 'Dela Gothic One', cursive;;
}

body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.logo{
color:white;
padding: 13px;
width: 30%;
}

.menu-principal{
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
}

main{
width: 980px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.redes-sociais ul li{
display:inline-block;
width: 20%;
float: right;
}

Answer (score -3):

Dá uma olhadinha nesses vídeos pode te ajudar muito:

```
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLirko8T4cEmx5eBb1-9j6T6Gl4aBtZ_5x
```

Você pode usar essa attr CSS:

```
style="display: inline-flex;align-items: center;"
```

Tanta arrumar um pouco seu html, você pode fazer algo próximo assim:

```
<div style="display: inline-flex;align-items: center;">
                <!--menu principal-->
                <div class="">
                    <h2>WANTED</h2>
                </div>

                <!--logo-->
                <div class="redes-sociais">
                    <ul>

                        <li>
                            <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]